# WikiData SPARQL query gives different numbers with and without labels

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to download from Wikidata the journals with their OpenAlex id.

This query tells me that there are about **85k**

```
SELECT  (COUNT (?entity) as ?entries)
WHERE
{
  ?entity wdt:P31/wdt:P279? wd:Q737498. 
  ?entity wdt:P10283 ?xopenalex_id .
}
```

More or less the same if I add *optionally* issn_l

```
SELECT DISTINCT  (COUNT (?entity) as ?entries)
WHERE
{
  ?entity wdt:P31/wdt:P279? wd:Q737498. 
  ?entity wdt:P10283 ?xopenalex_id
  OPTIONAL { ?entity wdt:P7363 ?xissnl}.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en, de,fr, ru" } .
}
```

But when I try to download the data I get about **20k** less

both following queries return about **65k**

*(I wrap them in a python script using **wikidataintegrator**)*

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ?entity  ?xopenalex_id  
WHERE
{
  ?entity wdt:P31/wdt:P279? wd:Q737498. 
  ?entity wdt:P10283 ?xopenalex_id 
}
```

and this with issn_l

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ?entity ?entityLabel  ?xopenalex_id  ?xissnl
WHERE
{
  ?entity wdt:P31/wdt:P279? wd:Q737498. 
  ?entity wdt:P10283 ?xopenalex_id
  OPTIONAL { ?entity wdt:P7363 ?xissnl}.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en, de,fr, ru" } .
}
```

any idea, what I am missing ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `DISTINCT` matters.

Comment: Thanks an Joshua Taylor for the edits. Thanks @Stanislav Kralin : but all the queries have DISTINCT in them or am I overlooking something ? This dashboard also show that there are about 85k items with OpenAlex Id https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/User:Mugabal

Comment: The first query doesn't have `DISTINCT`. It should be `SELECT  (COUNT (DISTINCT ?entity) AS ?entries)` etc.

Comment: thanks @stanislav-kralin. Silly me. Indeed the difference disappears with DISTINCT. Still puzzled though by the apparent duplicates ... (on which end?) . I will compare the sets with and without DISTINCT. If insightful I will post it here, if not, maybe I should just delete the question ? Thanks anyway

Comment: The source of duplicates is `?`. Some entities are instances of  wd:Q737498 both immediately and through other direct subclasses of wd:Q737498. https://w.wiki/58dT

Comment: thanks. it makes sense and is at the same time a relief. I did most of the OpenAlex matching (via quick statements) and was afraid I made a mistake.  Looking at my queries, I should have realized that there is a different between ```SELECT DISTINCT  (COUNT (?entity) as ?entries)``` and ```SELECT  (COUNT (DISTINCT ?entity) AS ?entries)```.  The last (yours) is the correct one